# C# code conversion to VB with LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am trying to convert the 2 routines below into VB and I am having problems with the free Telerik converter.  It generally works perfectly fine.

The routines are C# extension routines to find windows forms controls that match a particular type of control or control with a name recursively:

```
   public static IEnumerable<T> FindAllChildrenByType<T>(this Control control)
   {
        var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();
        var enumerable = controls as IList<Control> ?? controls.ToList();
        return enumerable
            .OfType<T>()
            .Concat<T>(enumerable.SelectMany(FindAllChildrenByType<T>));
    }

    public static T FindChildByType<T>(this Control control, String ctrlName)
    {
        foreach (var ctrl in from ctrl in FindAllChildrenByType<T>(control) let testControl = ctrl as Control where testControl != null && testControl.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == ctrlName.ToUpperInvariant() select ctrl)
        {
            return ctrl;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

What I got from the Telerik website is as follows:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)(control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim controls As Control() = control.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
    Dim enumerable As IEnumerable = If(TryCast(controls, IList(Of Control)), controls.ToList())
    Return enumerable.OfType(Of T).Concat(enumerable.SelectMany(AddressOf FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)))
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function FindChildByType(Of T)(control As Control, ctrlName As String) As T
    For Each ctrl As T In From ctrl In FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)(control) Let testControl = TryCast(ctrl, Control) Where testControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso testControl.Name.ToUpperInvariant() = ctrlName.ToUpperInvariant() Select ctrl
        Return ctrl
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

These routines work perfectly fine when used in C#, I need to go back in time a bit to use these routines in VB.

Thanks very much!

Don B.

Comment: Why are you converting C# to VB? I'm honestly curious.

Comment: `I am having problems` are they a secret?

Comment: As mentioned by @Plutonix, more info is required, what are the errors you are getting in VB?

Comment: So, I thought it was clear, but obviously clarity is in the eyes of the beholder.  The problems I am having are is that the code supplied by Telerik doesn't compile.

Comment: Also, the reason I am converting from C# to VB is that I have a large old VB project for which I'd like to fix some things and use some newer C# constructs.  No money to convert entirely to C# so thus the need to backport to VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the conversion:

1. It's not using Option Infer On - the VB equivalent to 'var' is to leave off the type and use Option Infer On. This is the only problem with the first method conversion. The converter tried to guess these and got them wrong - there's no need to guess - let Option Infer do this.
2. The second method uses 'ctrl' twice in the same scope - don't know why C# allows this. Rename the 'outer' For Each variable.

The corrected VB code is the following (note that the extension methods need to be inside a 'Module'):

```
Option Infer On

Module Test
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)(control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim controls = control.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
        Dim enumerable = If(TryCast(controls, IList(Of Control)), controls.ToList())
        Return enumerable.OfType(Of T).Concat(enumerable.SelectMany(AddressOf FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)))
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function FindChildByType(Of T)(control As Control, ctrlName As String) As T
        For Each ctrlx In From ctrl In FindAllChildrenByType(Of T)(control) Let testControl = TryCast(ctrl, Control) Where testControl IsNot Nothing AndAlso testControl.Name.ToUpperInvariant() = ctrlName.ToUpperInvariant() Select ctrl
            Return ctrlx
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I think `ctrl` is allowed twice in the C# code because they are not actually in the same scope in the C# code. `var ctrl` is within the scope of the `foreach` loop, whereas `from ctrl` is within the scope of the query expression. Not sure why that's different in VB.NET though.

Comment: Dave, thanks so much for your answer.  I generally don't like using the Infer option but but even after I do add it to my module, I still get a compile error in VS2015 Enterprise.  I took a screen capture to show you the error, but basically the error is in the TryCast(ctrl, Control) where the Control token is underlined in red and the error says: Cannot cast expression of type 'T' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: Lastly, please don't spend too much time on this, I can always just link in a dll with the orig C# code.

Comment: Strange - I don't get this error in VS 2015 - the code I posted compiles fine (with Option Infer On).